# Read the computer's RSA key fingerprint from Android

Tags: android, security, adb

I want to read the fingerprint of the computer. That fingerprint is shown when you connect it for the first time with your computer.

I googled a lot but I found nothing related. Do you have an idea or a helpful resource?

Comment: It seems that the keys are stored in `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`.

Comment: The "fingerprint" is just an MD5 hash of the computer's public key, which is stored in `~/.android/adbkey.pub` in `base64` encoding.

Comment: @AlexP. I already read that, but I cannot read that file from the Android device.

Comment: This is handled internally by the adbd daemon, so there is nothing you can do without modifying it. The PC acts as a host, so you can't really send commands from Android either. If you want to identify the host, the host has to send you some identifier proactively as part of some protocol. Why do you need to identify the host anyway?

Comment: That was an idea for a developer backdoor, since some devices have bugs when using `abd shell run-as`. That idea was also restricted to debug builds.

Comment: This related question might have some leads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891108/how-to-get-list-of-usb-accessories-connected-to-android-device

Answer (score 39):

Enter this in your terminal:

```
awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl md5 -c
```

Works just as it should for me. =)

From: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50922/how-can-i-see-the-fingerprint-of-my-adbkey?newreg=7d7d931b67d442019d3ba60ed114be04

which references the original source: http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html

Comment: Please correct me but this code is run on the computer right? I'm asking out of view of the app (on the mobile). By the way did you read the comments below the question?

Comment: oops, my bad. Yeah, I did read the comments, but totally missed that you were doing this from your Android device. You could try the command in a terminal emulator on Android?

Comment: That is not possible. I basically want to know if a mobile is connected to a specific computer.

Comment: @scorpiodawg no. By the way the question would be a better place for this comment.

Comment: on modern hardware/software hash-function md5 is replaced with other, e.g sha256, also could try `awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl sha256 -c`

Comment: @Marisha sounds like case-by-case basis, I'm using Samsung S22 Ultra (released in 2022) and Motorola G60S (2021) and they encrypt RSA keys using md5.

Answer (score -1):

On Android 5 and up as far as I know hash-function `md5` is replaced with `sha256`,  try:

`awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl sha256 -c | awk '{print $2}'|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`

Comment: Please read the question! I was asking to identify the computer from the mobile!